# solve $54 x + 16 y = 2400$ for integer values of x,y

Tags: algorithms, combinations, problem-solving, integer-programming

How to get **integer** values for x and y that satisfy: $$54  x + 16  y = 2400$$

Someone told me that I can do it using Euclid-Wallis algorithm, but I don't understand it so, if there isn't any else solution, can you explain it to me? I'm elementary.

Comment: Are you trying to solve this problem in the integers?

Comment: yep, x and y should be integers, without float.

Answer (score 3):

First simplify it to $27x+8y=1200$.

Then $27x = 1200 - 8y = 8(150-y)$.

Since $27$ and $8$ are coprime, this implies that $x=8z$ and so $27z=150-y$.

Therefore, the general solution is $x=8z$, $y=150-27z$.

Comment: thanks, but i need to somehow get all 6 combinations. I'm making an computer program to print all of the combinations

Comment: @Daniel  Substitute different integer values for $z$.  If you mean non-negative integer values for $x$ and $y$, observe that $0 < 150 - 27z \leq 150$ if $0 \leq z \leq 5$ and $x = 8z \geq 0$ if $z \geq 0$.

Comment: What would the procedure be if 8 and 27 weren't co prime ?

Comment: @user230452, you'd divide by their gcd and then they'd be coprime.

Answer (score 0):

Its a line, so solve for y

y = 150 - 27/8x

which has a y intercept of 150 and an x intercept of ~44. So sample every integer between 0 and 44, and by trial and error you will get all integer roots.

But for this particular case, I can do you one better. The only x integers will have a factor of 8. So {0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40}. In fact, with any line, the integer solutions will be found at values where both x and y are integers, which in our case will only happen if x is a factor of 8. Therefore there are 6 integer roots. (And to find y plug the x back into the original equation to solve in O(1))